# Youtube API Video stops when not on full screen

Tags: android, api, video, youtube

I'm using the youtube API and I did the instructions from this tutorial:

http://javatechig.com/android/youtubeplayerview-example-in-android-using-youtube-api

All is well, but when I'm not on full screen, the video keeps stopping every second. It's like it plays for 1 second, stops, then I have to press the play button again, then it will stop again after 1 second. On full screen, it plays perfectly. I'm 100% sure it's not the internet connection because I tried it with many connections and it ONLY plays properly on full screen. Any idea how I can fix this?

EDIT: It's not the phone either, I tried it on a Nexus 5, Sony Xperia z1, HTC One, a number of Samsung Galaxies. I rechecked the code multiple times, it's exactly the same, even did a copy paste of the tutorial. It still stops when it's not on full screen. I only used the tutorial, since I wanted to make sure it works before embedding it to my main project.

Comment: So you used the exact same code?

Comment: Yes I did :( I tried running it on my friends' phones as well, same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the padding in the youtube video player. It now plays perfectly regardless of orientation.